# Limit number of results with :gt() selector

Tags: jquery

I know I can use the `gt` selector to target all elements after a certain index, but what if I want to affect only a certain number of elements, for example the first 3?

So the following will give yellow background to all `tds` after index 4:

```
<table border="1">
  <tr><td>TD #0</td><td>TD #1</td><td>TD #2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>TD #3</td><td>TD #4</td><td>TD #5</td></tr>
  <tr><td>TD #6</td><td>TD #7</td><td>TD #8</td></tr>
</table>

$( "td:gt(4)" ).css( "backgroundColor", "yellow" );
```

But what if I wanted to target only the first 2 `tds` after index 4, not all of them?

Comment: this might sound stupid `$( "td:gt(4)" ).css( "backgroundColor", "yellow" );$("td:gt(6)").css("backgroundColor", "white");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try with:

```
$("td:gt(4):lt(2)").css("backgroundColor", "yellow");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RdaGd/1/

Comment: it still colors all of them.

Answer (score 0):

i thought it would work with

```
$( "td:gt(4):lt(2)" ).css( "backgroundColor", "yellow" );
```

i have another solution

```
$( "td" ).slice(5, 7).css( "backgroundColor", "yellow" );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EL9VW/

Comment: `lt` isn't working for me either. using `gt` is a MUST, so your other solution doesn't help me.